# NVIDIA data-science-stack ==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

Tags: data-science, nvidia

I cloned the repository for nvidias data-science-stack, went into the directory, and followed the instructions in README.md.

after I build the container by executing ./data-science-stack build-container

I get a prompt that says ==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

I have no clue what to do here. I close the terminal, open a terminal, go into the directory again, and when I run ./data-science-stack run-container

it says Unable to find image 'data-science-stack:2.8.0' locally
and that pull access is denied. I also executed ./data-science-stack setup-user

I have also included screenshots of these windows. Keep in mind, I'm following the directions in README.md exactly. They're rather simple directions. Either they're missing a step, or I am. Please help.[image]

[image]